# Are there any sort of chief pantheon in Japanese mythology? Who do they consist of?

Tags: folklore, japanese, mythohistory, pantheon, shinto

I've read some of the more well known ones like Izanagi and Izanami...Amaterasu, Tsukuyomi, Susanoo, and Orochi... I mostly want to know about the Shinto side but Japanese Buddhism legends are good too. I know about Hotei/Budai on that end. Mostly, because I have to remind people that though he is a Buddha he's not Siddhartha Gautama.

"Are there any sort of chief pantheon, a la the Olympians, in Japanese mythology? Who do they consist of?" This question but you don't have to add in the former gods I've listed. Nothing fancy.

Comment: This isn't really a good place for story recommendations. Maybe try using the chat?.

Comment: I voted to close this, however, I think with some tweaking it could work. I'll try giving it a thorough edit later and hopefully making this fit the StackExchange format.

Comment: I'm just looking for more myths to learn more about how the Japanese tied them into their religion..? Its like asking for Greek myths to learn more about the Olympians. People can list of lots of Greek gods and their stories... I'm asking the same of Japanese gods....but I guess if someone feels like they need to change the question.. be my guest.

Comment: @Hush564 The problem is that it is too broad and too based on personal opinions. An example of the sort of questions we usually want here is something like, *"Does Japan have a creation myth and if so what is it?"* Or perhaps, *"Are there any sort of chief pantheon, a la the Olympians, in Japanese mythology? Who do they consist of?"*. You could you list some deities and ask how they are related, too; but asking for a family tree of the entirety of Shinto gods is a bit daunting.

Comment: @Semaphore I know of the creation story. I want the lesser known stories.
Even if I put in "Are there any sort of chief pantheon, a la the Olympians, in Japanese mythology? Who do they consist of?" THAT is almost the same exact thing that I am asking for. A list of gods that people can pull from the top of their heads. I'm not asking for hours of research. Just interesting stories that I can go look up. Directing me to better sites a wiki page.

Comment: It's a good start. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Hush564 You should also put that in the title, so that it matches the body of the question. I've edited and reopened for you this time but just keep that in mind if you ask more questions, thanks.

Comment: There isn't really a concrete list. I tend to use this site for any research or questions I have: http://eos.kokugakuin.ac.jp/modules/xwords/category.php?categoryID=4&start=0

Comment: @Pleiades oh my that is a really good link! Thank you!

Comment: @Hush564: It's one of my favorites for a reason. It's incredibly useful, albeit a tad unorganized. I think it'll serve you well though.

Comment: @Pleiades yeah it seems a bit disheveled. But I hope to learn some new things :) it seems like there isn't that much information about this topic like in other areas of mythos/religion.

Comment: Well, Shintoism isn't exactly a very defined religion, and there are only really three primary texts we can pull information from. I'm attempting to learn how to read Japanese calligraphy since I have a solid enough grasp on kobun, but I still don't think there's too much I'll uncover that others haven't. That site's going to be your best bet, as far as English resources go.

Comment: @Pleiades yeah, the way the Japanese treat religion as opposed to the West is interesting. It's very fluid with the way they will mix Shinto with Buddhism and even Christianity. :)